# string offset as an array

Tags: php, drupal, multidimensional-array, fatal-error

I am working in drupal 6, but I think this is more of a php related question than a drupal question.

I am using regex to collect certain values from an the $node object, based on the key I assign the value to a new array to pass this to another function of mine.

Sometimes I get the "Fatal error: Cannot use string offset as an array" error and sometimes I dont...

Here is the code I am using

```
$dynamic_acc = array();
      foreach($node as $key => $value){            
        //regular expression of the required fields
        $opt_exp = "/^(field_svm_group_and_or_)(\d*)(_qlty)$/";
        $min_exp = "/^(field_svm_group_min_acc_)(\d*)(_qlty)$/";
        $max_exp = "/^(field_svm_group_max_acc_)(\d*)(_qlty)$/";
        if(preg_match($opt_exp, $key)){
          $id_array = preg_split('/_/', $key); //$id_array['5'] will always be an integer
          $dynamic_acc[$id_array['5']]['opt'] = array(
              $key => $value['0']['value'],
              );
        }
        if(preg_match($min_exp, $key)){
          $id_array = preg_split('/_/', $key);
          $dynamic_acc[$id_array['5']]['min'] = array(
              $key => ($value['0']['value'])/(100),
              );
        }
        if(preg_match($max_exp, $key)){
          $id_array = preg_split('/_/', $key);
          $dynamic_acc[$id_array['5']]['max'] =array(
              $key => ($value['0']['value'])/(100),
              );
        }

      }
```

I have read up about the error on php.net and here on stackoverflow... but I dont really grasp the concept. If anyone could help me out and give me some insight into this issue, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: ok... I feel really stupid!! $value[0]['value'] doesn't exist :( I was just programming like a monkey.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably $value['0'] is a string and you're trying to treat it as an array.

This error commes up when you do this:

```
$foo = 'bar';
$foo[0] = 'barbar';
```